# PHP, add temporary only value into array

Tags: php, arrays, temporary

I've got code:

```
foreach( $postData as $d => $a ) {
    if( in_array( $d, $existingDomains ) ) {
        foreach( $a as $p => $v ) {
            echo "\t\t$d : $p = $v<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to add to the $existingDomains array, one value only for the purpose of this one loop. Of course I can array_push() and later unset(), but my question is if I can make it something like this:

```
if( in_array( $d, $existingDomains + [ 'some_value' ] ) ) { }
```

Comment: `if( in_array( $d, array_merge($existingDomains, ['some_value']) ) ) {...}`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much thats the thing I was searching for :D So simple yet I haven't thought about it :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of temporarily adding an element to your array and then running in_array. How about using an `or` statement instead?

```
if($d == 'some_value' || in_array($d,$existingDomains))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also a good solution, but I was rather searching for something what has Mark Baker suggested.